# How can I include different navigations for my website using HTML?

Tags: html, browser, include, agent, ssi

I have an html website that has a "computer" web style to it, and then a style for mobile. The problem is the mobile navigation has pipes separating the navigation and I don't need the pipes on the "computer" web style. How can I include the different navigations for the different agents?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the markup so it makes sense everywhere.

You shouldn't separate navigation items with pipe characters, ASCII art doesn't play well with semantic markup.

Use list items for all your navigation, and style it differently using media queries. You can use a border on one side of the list items to create the appearance of a vertical line between items.